# Increasing The Size Of View In ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, tabview

I have a list View . I want to show the following field in each row .

```
 1. An Image 
 2. An TextView For Book Name
 3. An TextView For Author Name
 4. An TextView For File Type
```

All thing is successfully done by me . But the size of each row in the list view is not sufficient for showing all this feature as explained in the image .

[image]

The code for creating this :

```
if( row_view == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            row_view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null,true) ;
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView_for_BookName = (TextView) row_view.findViewById(R.id.book_text_view_book_tab);
            holder.textView_For_fileType = (TextView) row_view.findViewById(R.id.type_for_book_tab);
            holder.textView_Forauthor = (TextView) row_view.findViewById(R.id.author_text_view_book_tab);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) row_view.findViewById(R.id.image_sd_list_view);
            row_view.setTag(holder);
        }
```

The Code of rowLayout.xml is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#FFFFFF"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/image_sd_list_view"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:text="Book Name"
        android:id="@+id/book_text_view_book_tab">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author_text_view_book_tab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Author Name"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="13dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="File Type :"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:id="@+id/type_for_book_tab">
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to show the above field (book_name,author_name,file_type) in each textView . For that , I have to increase the size of each row in the listView . What to do for increasing the size of row in list view ?? Please hlep ....

Comment: try changing the size of the image to some value that fits your requirement.

Comment: I can not like this idea . Can you come forward with another idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to set the root layout's height in `row_layout.xml` to `wrap_content` (or a larger static value).

```
android:height="wrap_content"
```

(If you need more specific help, you need to post `row_layout.xml`.)

---

Try changing both of your LinearLayout's `height` attributes:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    />
```

Comment: I can not understand your statement . Can you please tell me about it more ? The code of "row_layout.xml" is just added for you ease of discussion .